# Facebook check the validity of the token on PHP

Tags: php, facebook

I did authorization with facebook in PHP for this example https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_facebook_login/

Facebook has test documentation
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/testing-your-login-flow/

Take for example this "6. Someone changes the Facebook password after logging in with Facebook to your app".

To implement this, I take a token from the session and check whether the token has expired. I do this every time a user opens a page of the site.

Everything worked fine and the user left the session for example when changing the password from facebook. But now facebook has made rate limits and when I do a check for an expired token, it ends quickly.

I don't understand what I have to do with this. How do I check the validity of a token in PHP? Please help.

```php
if(key_exists('fb_token', $_SESSION))
{
    $tokenMetadata = facebook()->getOAuth2Client()->debugToken(
        $_SESSION['fb_token']
    );

    if($tokenMetadata->getIsValid())
        return $_SESSION['fb_user_id'];

    return false;
}
```

Comment: You can only check the validity of a token by either debugging it - or by making any other API call, whereupon the response will tell you that the token has expired. I guess Facebook wants you to do the latter - not constantly test if the token is still valid, but react accordingly once it has actually expired (either due to time restrictions, or because the user changed their account password.)

Comment: But how do I know? Do I still have to constantly check the validity of the token?

Comment: No, you just make your normal API calls - and check what the response is. In case it’s an error, you check type and code to figure out if it was due to an expired token, and react accordingly. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/error-handling/

Comment: But I don't need to call the API after the user has logged in. But I need to know that a person should be logout if he changed the password for example from facebook. And that's how I find out I don't understand.

Comment: You don’t have to actively log them out, that is not what point 6) of the document you referred to says. That is rather impossible to begin with, if you use the server-side login flow only - other than by making API requests to debug the token all the time. If the JS SDK was embedded on the page, it should recognize that at the next page load though.